# Are shrine effects predetermined?

Tags: starbound

My friend and I were running across a planet willy nilly in Starbound and ran across one of the common status pods (the rotating shrine-like ones, not the breakable pods). After activating it and getting bombs everywhere, we got into a joke argument that if the other had done it, it would have been better. This turned into a discussion as to whether or not this would actually be the case.

**Are status pods predetermined before you activate them or does it randomly pick upon use?**

Answer (score 1):

## The status pods are random

Details about the status pods are found at:
http://starbounder.org/Status_Pod